# ROS Beginner Tutorials: Examining the Simple Service and Client (python) - need some help

Tags: python, service, beginner-tutorials, server, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I'm following the **ROS Tutorials** and, using the *Python* language, I'm currently having some issues trying to solve the item **Examining the Simple Service and Client** item ([link text](http: // www.ros .org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/ExaminingServiceClient)).

When I try to run the **server** (the first step in the tutorial), I get the following message:

```
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py
Unable to register with master node [http :// localhost:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
```

And then my Terminal window gets blocked. Before that, when I compiled the code (from the previous tutorial: http :// www.ros .org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) everything seems to work fine:

```
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/viki/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/viki/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/home/viki/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  7%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[  7%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 10%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 10%] Built target beginner_tutorials_generate_messages
[ 11%] Built target roscpp_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 11%] Built target roscpp_tutorials_gencpp
[ 12%] Built target add_two_ints_client
[ 14%] Built target add_two_ints_server
[ 15%] Built target add_two_ints_server_class
[ 16%] Built target anonymous_listener
[ 18%] Built target babbler
[ 19%] Built target custom_callback_processing
[ 20%] Built target listener
[ 22%] Built target listener_async_spin
[ 23%] Built target listener_class
[ 24%] Built target listener_multiple
[ 25%] Built target listener_threaded_spin
[ 27%] Built target listener_unreliable
[ 28%] Built target listener_with_tracked_object
[ 29%] Built target listener_with_userdata
[ 31%] Built target node_handle_namespaces
[ 32%] Built target notify_connect
[ 33%] Built target parameters
[ 36%] Built target roscpp_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 37%] Built target roscpp_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 37%] Built target roscpp_tutorials_generate_messages
[ 38%] Built target talker
[ 40%] Built target time_api_sleep
[ 41%] Built target timers
[ 49%] Built target rospy_tutorials_generate_messages_py
[ 54%] Built target rospy_tutorials_generate_messages_lisp
[ 59%] Built target rospy_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp
[ 59%] Built target rospy_tutorials_generate_messages
[ 59%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 59%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 68%] Built target turtlesim_generate_messages_cpp
[ 68%] Built target turtlesim_gencpp
[ 70%] Built target draw_square
[ 71%] Built target mimic
[ 72%] Built target turtle_teleop_key
[ 72%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
[ 72%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 84%] Built target turtlesim_generate_messages_py
[ 84%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 84%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 93%] Built target turtlesim_generate_messages_lisp
[ 93%] Built target turtlesim_generate_messages
[100%] Built target turtlesim_node
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$
```

When I try `roswtf` I get no error:

```
viki@ROS:~/catkin_ws$ roswtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================ Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be
running. Online graph checks will not
be run. ROS_MASTER_URI is
[http :// localhost:11311]
```

I haven't found any clues on the web related to this and I can't figure it out what's really happening.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance,

Batta

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70546/ros-beginner-tutorials:-examining-the-simple-service-and-client-(python)---need-some-help/) by [Batta](https://answers.ros.org/users/5117/batta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is normally the problem when you have not done **Environment setup**
There are few steps you need to perform before doing any thing else. I think you missed one step out of that which we need to perform after proper installation of ROS **that is Environment setup**

**Please visit following link and make sure you have perform steps from 1.1 to 1.7** if you have not done so far ....

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu

If you have already done the environmental setup then you need to run **roscore** command that is the master program through which all other program communicate to get performed in ROS .....

```
$ roscore
```

I hope your problem will be solved by that.

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-02**:
Since catkin_make succeeded, the environment is probably configured properly.

But, as @lifelonglearner says, you must start `roscore` in a separate terminal before you can issue `rosrun beginner_tutorials add_two_ints_server.py`.